# is there a lightning experience version of the send email page?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, email-template, send-email

We have some url link buttons on a few pages that go to the Send Email page in classic that loads an email template, allows for editing, and then sends. This is all OOTB functionality (other than the url button). We are converting to lightning and converting these buttons to quick actions. Is there a lightning version of the Send Email page? I was unable to find one or anything about it.

Question 2:
 I started recreating the send email page in lihgtning on my own but the problem is that the template being pulled in has merge fields and the custom component just displays the merge field text in the rich text editor because the text doesnt match the lightning web component syntax for data access. Has anyone  done this?

[image: Send Email Page]